# richface fileupload file size restricted error

Tags: richfaces, seam, redhat, jboss6.x

I am using richface 3.3.3 with Seam 2.2., Jboss 6.1
I am using the trying to use rich:fileupload component. i get error on files above 10 MB when i deploy my Code on a linux server, when i try the exact same code on my windows server it works fine with files upto 1.9GB.

Windows 7,Ubuntu as server works fine. 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago) dosn't work.

I go the following settings in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>1900000000</param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My file uppload component.

```
   <rich:fileUpload id="fileUploadId" uploadControlLabel="Ladda Ner"
                addControlLabel="Filer..." cancelEntryControlLabel="Ta bort"
                maxFilesQuantity="1000" uploadButtonClassDisabled="invisible"
                stopButtonClass="invisible"  onadd="_onaddHandler(event);" onerror="_onerrorhandle(event);"
                fileUploadListener="#{deliveryInAction.fileUploadListener}"
                onupload="Richfaces.showModalPanel('wait-dialog-upload');"
                onuploadcomplete="archive();" allowFlash="auto" styleClass="syll-file-upload"/>
```

Comment: Please what exactly do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get van exception or some warning about the file size? Can you put a debug line within the managed bean to display the context-param value during an upload?

Comment: Yeah done that the context param value is as it should however it never gets in to the richface filter. Dosn't work means in the rich component it returns error file size restricted. i copied my whole jboss from my RedHat server to an ubuntu server and run it there and there it worked as well (i ziped the jboss folder and unziped on ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, had a front end Nginx with max_body_size : 10M changed that it it worked.